# sudo environment: "g++: command not found"

Tags: rhel, sudo, gcc, g++

I have a relatively fresh RHEL 6.5 install, on to which I have installed from source GCCC 4.9.  After I installed GCC 4.9, I uninstalled the distro-provided older GCC version via:

```
sudo yum remove gcc
```

GCC *appears* to be correctly installed and visible to both users and `root`, but when I try to issue a `sudo` command which needs the compiler, it cannot be found.

It seems to me that `PATH` doesn't point to `g++` during `sudo`, but I don't understand why.

`g++` is installed in:

```
[john@haley boost_1_55_0]$ which g++
/usr/local/bin/g++
```

And getting the version as a user and as `root` succeeds:

```
[john@haley boost_1_55_0]$ g++ --version
g++ (GCC) 4.9.0
Copyright (C) 2014 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

[john@haley boost_1_55_0]$ sudo su -
root@haley /root # g++ --version
g++ (GCC) 4.9.0
Copyright (C) 2014 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

But `sudo g++ --version` fails:

```
john@haley boost_1_55_0]$ sudo g++ --version
[sudo] password for john: 
sudo: g++: command not found
[john@haley boost_1_55_0]$
```

Checking the `PATH` as `sudo`:

```
[john@haley boost_1_55_0]$ sudo echo $PATH
/usr/lib64/qt-3.3/bin:/usr/local/:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/home/john/bin:/usr/local/bin
                                                                             ^^^^^^^^^
```

... seems to indicate that the location of `g++` is actually in the path.

Why is this failing, and what can I do to fix it?

Answering questions in comments:

yes, I can execute it using explicit paths under `sudo`:

```
[john@haley boost_1_55_0]$ sudo /usr/local/bin/g++ --version
[sudo] password for john: 
g++ (GCC) 4.9.0
Copyright (C) 2014 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

[john@haley boost_1_55_0]$
```

It was observed that I was doing-it-wrong when checking the `sudo PATH`.  Doing it the right way reveals that in fact `/usr/local/bin` is *not* in `sudo`'s `PATH`:

```
[john@haley boost_1_55_0]$ sudo env | grep PATH
13:PATH=/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
[john@haley boost_1_55_0]$
```

Comment: Can you execute it if you use absolute pathnames with `sudo`?

Comment: @psimon:  Yes; question edited with demo.

Comment: The way you're checking `$PATH` is wrong because `$PATH` expanded by the shell.  Try `sudo env | grep PATH`.

Comment: @Mikel:  Quite right.  Doing it the right way confirms that the directory is **not** in sudo's path.  Question edited with demo.

Comment: Should I `visudo` and add `/usr/local/bin` to the `secure_path`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm posting this as an answer because I discovered this solution through comments on the OP, but I'm not sure that this is what I *should* do.

I can make this work by running `sudo visudo` and editing the `secure_path` to include `/usr/local/bin`.

On my system, the original line is:

```
Defaults    secure_path = /sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
```

Changing it to:

```
Defaults    secure_path = /sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin
```

"fixes" the problem:

```
[john@haley boost_1_55_0]$ sudo g++ --version
g++ (GCC) 4.9.0
Copyright (C) 2014 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

[john@haley boost_1_55_0]$
```